# Laser scans of buildings / cities

Tags: data-request, city

I am looking for a point cloud source of laser scanned building. I have found Laser scans of Earth surface, but there is no open archive of scanned cities / buildings. Or is there something?

I dont care about location, I just need some real-life data for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php?type=residential) dataset ? Some sets are in urban areas.
Maybe you can also have a look on the [Eisats](http://ccv.wordpress.fos.auckland.ac.nz/eisats/set-6/) dataset.